# vb.net: Using <see> Tags in XML comments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

I'm trying to improve my code documentation and decided to give XML-comments a closer look.

If I'm not mistaken, the `<see>` Tag should allow to create clickable "links" or references to other parts of code.

pE:

```vb
Public Class Form1  

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Does something.
  ''' </summary>
  Private Sub aaa()
      'do something
  End Sub  

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Calls <see cref="aaa"/>.
  ''' </summary>
  Private Sub bbb()
      aaa()
  End Sub  

End Class
```

This should create a clickable link to "aaa" in the documentation of "bbb".

The xml-code compiles just fine, intellisense even helps with choosing what to reference, but in the objectbrowser it doesn't work! The reference to "aaa" is just dead text.

Do you have any ideas on this? It would be a neat little feature if it worked.

(I'm working on VS2010Premium)

Comment: Documentation says there these links only make sense for [some external tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc837134%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The object browser does not show `<see>` links between help pages of built-in types either.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your answer!
So sad - I really liked the idea.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2015, the see tag will cause hyperlinks to referenced objects to appear within IntelliSense views.  Object Viewer support for these hyperlinks is still missing.

The following example demonstrates the IntelliSense functionality (vb.net):

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the collection of source XML files.  See <see cref="imbuddy.Collections.ImeXmlFilePaths"/>
''' </summary>
''' <returns>See <see cref="imbuddy.Collections.ImeXmlFilePaths"/></returns>
Public ReadOnly Property SourceXmlFiles As Collections.ImeXmlFilePaths
```